# How to download a pdf file using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

```
void getHttp() async 
  {
    print("Got called");
    var response = await Dio().download('https://www.google.com/', 'assets/xx.html');

    print("DDDDD:");
    print(response);
  }
```

The directory assets is present with read and write permissions.

I am calling this on the press of a button. "Got called" DOES get printed.
There are no errors present, still "DDDDD" doesn't get printed.
The `xx.html` doesn't get saved.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) the syntax for `Dio` to download a file is

```
var response = await Dio().download('https://www.google.com/', <<Destination directory from which your app is running. Like internal storage or external storage.>>);
```

I guess you are providing the file path which is associated with the projects assets directory where the file cannot be downloaded since it is bundled with the app.

Use the following [package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to access the device file system and provide that path to download your file.

```
 var response = await Dio().download('https://www.google.com/', <<Path from internal storage.>>);
```